# Place a heading at the top of a page on the grid

Tags: context, grid-typesetting

In the following example the first heading should be placed on the *second* grid line while the space between "Heading" and "Subheading" should remain as is. Interestingly, the `grid` options `high`, `low` and `box` yield the same result as `none` (in `\setuphead[section]`). All other options from the "It's in the details" manual move the heading down a line as desired, *but also affect the spacing between the headings*.

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\showgrid

\setupwhitespace[line]

\setuphead
    [section]
    [style=\bfc,
     before=,
     after=,
     grid=none]
\setuphead
    [subsection]
    [style=\bfb,
     before=,
     after=,
     grid=none]


\starttext

\startsection[title={Heading}]

\startsubsection[title={Subheading}]

\input ward

\input ward

\stopsubsection

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How many lines should be between section and subsection?

Comment: Does `\setuphead[section][style=\bfc,before={\blank[packed]\blank[force,depth]},aftersection={\phantom{}\blank[force,height]},grid=none]` help?

Comment: @DG' section should sit on the second grid line (so its ascenders won't protrude the text frame), subsection should sit on the fourth.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Yes! In fact, just modifying the `before` option helps.